# Determining required precision and scale for decimal data type columns in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, decimal, precision

I have a huge number of MariaDB 10.6 tables with several `decimal(P,D)` columns and millions of rows. The precision (`P`) and the scale (`D`) of these columns were once set to unrealistic high levels, just accommodate every possible input, e.g. `decimal(24,10)`.

Now I would like to determine the required `P` and `D` values based on the actual data in these tables.

The best I could come up with is

```sql
SELECT CEIL(LOG10(MAX(col))) AS maxI,
       MAX(CEIL(LOG10(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTR(CAST(col % 1 AS VARCHAR(12)), 3)) AS INT)))) AS maxD
FROM tbl;
```

where `col` is a column with data type `decimal(24,10)`, `maxI` the biggest integer part, and `maxP` the maximum number of significant digits after the decimal point (so `maxP = maxI + maxD`).

While it does work, it is unsurprisingly slow and I wonder whether there is a more efficient way to get there.

Comment: I would use `CEIL(LOG10(MAX(col)))`. If `col` has an index, it can calculate the max quickly.

Comment: And even if it doesn't, it doesn't have to call `LOG10` for every row, which is expensive.

Comment: I can't think of any efficient way to get `maxD`.

Comment: @Barmar I will edit the `maxI` part according to your input. The expensive part though is the `maxD`.

Comment: Maybe `MAX(LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '.', -1)))`

Comment: @Barmar `MAX(LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '.', -1)))` gives me the actual `D` and not the required one. With the data type set to `decimal(24,10)` I get 10 even if all values are integers.

Comment: Of course, that was stupid of me. You need to remove trailing zeroes, which could be done with `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Comment: You should use the *requirements,* not the actual data.

Comment: @user207421 The actual data defines the requirements!

Comment: MariaDB ain't MySQL. I have edited to make it more clear that you're using MariaDB, not MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar `MAX(LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '.', -1),'[0]+$','')))` actually works. Will check performance.

Comment: @Barmar The regex way doesn't really speed the query up much. I've just measured an average time reduction of 1.8%.

Comment: Then I'm back to my initial assessment: I don't think there's a way to get maxD efficiently. Indexes can't be used, it has to examine every row and process it as a string.

Comment: Maybe you could dump the column to a file and use a text processing tool like `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use double functions (like LOG10) when working with precision numbers to avoid warnings and rounding errors.

Calculating max digits before decimal point is quite simple, since this can be handled by the optimizer without touching the index. For unsigned decimal you can use `MAX()`, for signed decimals you have to use `MIN()` and `MAX()`:

```
select @maxI1:=LENGTH(TRUNCATE(MIN(col1),0)), @maxI2:=LENGTH(TRUNCATE(MAX(col1),0)) FROM tbl;
```

The most decimal digits has the record `MAX(col1 - TRUNCATE(col1,0))`.
So the 2nd statement would be:

```
SELECT IF(@maxI1 > @maxI2, @maxI1, @maxI2) as maxI,
       LENGTH(TRIM(MAX(col1 - TRUNCATE(col1, 0)))+0) -2 as maxD
FROM tbl;
```

Speed comparison (7 Mio rows):

```
SELECT CEIL(LOG10(MAX(col1))) AS maxI, MAX(CEIL(LOG10(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTR(CAST(col1 % 1 AS VARCHAR(12)), 3)) AS INT)))) AS maxD FROM tbl;
+------+------+
| maxI | maxD |
+------+------+
|   13 |   10 |
+------+------+
1 row in set, 40964 warnings (6.166 sec)
```

vs.

```
SELECT @maxI1:=LENGTH(TRUNCATE(MIN(col1),0)) as maxI1, @maxI2:=LENGTH(TRUNCATE(MAX(col1),0)) as maxI2 FROM tbl;
+-------+-------+
| maxI1 | maxI2 |
+-------+-------+
|     5 |    13 |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

SELECT IF(@maxI1 > @maxI2, @maxI1, @maxI2) as maxI, LENGTH(TRIM(MAX(col1 - TRUNCATE(col1, 0)))+0) -2 as maxD FROM tbl;
+------+------+
| maxI | maxD |
+------+------+
|   13 |    7 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (4.168 sec)
```

Comment: I am getting completely different results. If `@maxI1` is 5 and `@maxI2` is 13, then why would `IF(@maxI1 > @maxI2, LENGTH(@maxI1), LENGTH(@maxI2))` be 13? Shouldn't it be 2 instead? With your solution I neither get the correct `maxI` nor the `maxD` - `maxD` always equals `D`.

Comment: This solves the problem with `maxI`. But `maxD` is still equal to the specified scale `D` of the column.

Comment: Answer updated/corrected.

Comment: `MAX(value - TRUNCATE(value, 0)` gives us the max value without the integer part (e.g. 0.65) while we should find the "longest" one (0.21746). I come to agree with @Barmar that there is no way around strings.